# Eclipse plugin is not working on reinstalling

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am using a custom plugin which is integrated to the Eclipse IDE which is used at my workplace, this integration happens on Maven build. This plugin works fine. Now if I uninstall the custom plugin and reinstall the same custom plugin, it does not work. It throws

```
    javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(HttpClientTransport.java:195)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:226)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:217)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:130)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1121)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1035)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1004)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:862)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:448)
```

But I think this should not be an issue as the same plugin works with a standalone eclipse. Is there any why for me to enable logs so that I get to know what is happneing when I install or uninstall a plugin. The above logs

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in the Error Log? (**Window > Show View > Error Log**)

Comment: There was a dependency(Xtext) issue and I figured it out later. java.net.SocketTimeoutException was very misleading.   Thank you.

Comment: If you've found the solution, then please either post it as an answer, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem arises because of the firewall. I've had a similar problem, I hope this helps.